# Waiting for the r_gripper_sensor_controller/gripper_action action server to come up

Tags: ros, gazebo

I started to use ROS hydro (Robot Operating System) and roscpp.
I tested some examples to move the gripper of pr2 in Gazebo (especially the code in :  http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_gripper_sensor_action/Tutorials/Grab%20and%20Release%20an%20Object%20Using%20pr2_gripper_sensor_action ) with catkin package.

I launch : roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch

and when I run the node of code with : rosrun pack_name node_name, I get :: Waiting for the r_gripper_sensor_controller/gripper_action action server to come up ... Waiting for the r_gripper_sensor_controller/gripper_action action server to come up ...

I want to know the cause of those lines in order to see the results. what should I do??

it is notable that when I launch : roslaunch pr2_gripper_sensor_action pr2_gripper_sensor_actions.launch
      in the previous link, I get :

[pr2_gripper_sensor_actions.launch] is neither a launch file in package [pr2_gripper_sensor_action] nor is [pr2_gripper_sensor_action] a launch file name

Comment: These messages indicate that some [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) servers are not running.  Can you post a list of running nodes and/or your launch scripts?

Comment: ok. is it clear now??